# Tomcat 8 needs to restart after editing files

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat

I am using Tomcat 8.5 and eclipse 4.6.3 to develop a spring application. Every time when I change the code, I need to restart the server. I tried to change the context.xml file `reloadable="true"` and `autoDeploy="true"`. But still I need to restart the server after modifying codes.

Here the changed context.xml file's code,

`<Context docBase="regSpring" path="/regSpring" reloadable="true" autoDeploy="true">`

And I tried another method which is, double click on server->publishing->select "automatically publish when resources change".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restart tomcat when a class file is changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873920/restart-tomcat-when-a-class-file-is-changed)

Comment: @Hemin however the context.xml file was modified, so why we should restart again. Its difficult to test again and again

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer. Just **Clean and Build** the project. It will clear all temp files and memory, and re build the project again with modification.